# MongoDB: updating the value of an inner BSON

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document with a schema in mongodb that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("572f88424de8c74a69d4558c"),
    "storecode" : "ABC",
    "credit" : true,
    "group" : [
        {
            "group_name" : "Frequent_Buyer",
            "time" : NumberLong("1462732865712"),
        }
    ],
}
```

I want to add on the `_id` part for the first object in the array under `group` so it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("572f88424de8c74a69d4558c"),
    "storecode" : "ABC",
    "credit" : true,
    "group" : [
        {
            "group_name" : "Frequent_Buyer",
            "time" : NumberLong("1462732865712"),
            "_id" : "573216fee4430577cf35e885"
        }
    ],
}
```

When I try this code it fails:

```
db.customer.update({ "_id": ObjectId("572f88424de8c74a69d4558c") },{ "$set": { "group.$._id": "573216fee4430577cf35e885"} })

WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: groups.$._id"
    }
})
```

However, if I adjust the code slightly and add on an extra criteria for querying, it works:

```
db.customer.update({ "_id": ObjectId("572f88424de8c74a69d4558c"), "group.groupname": "Frequent_Buyer" },{ "$set": { "group.$._id": "573216fee4430577cf35e885"} })
```

**Results:**

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Why did the first command not work but the second command work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected result. To use the positional [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) update operator, the array field must appear as part of the query document as mentioned in the [documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

> When used with update operations, e.g. [db.collection.update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) and [db.collection.findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify),
>
> - the positional **$** operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, and
> - the array field must appear as part of the query document.

For example If you don't want to filter your documents using `group_name`, simply add  `group: { "$exists": true }` or `"group.0": { "$exists": true }` to your query criteria. You query will then look like this:

```js
db.customer.updateOne(
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("572f88424de8c74a69d4558c"), 
        "group.0": { "$exists": true}
    },
    { "$set": { "group.$._id": "573216fee4430577cf35e885" } }
)
```

Last and not least, you should be using `updateOne` or `updateMany` because update is deprecated in official language driver.

Comment: In the doc, does "the array field must appear as part of the query document." mean that you need to have a field from the inner array in your query to ensure the $ operator works?

Comment: @Simon No it means that you need the array field here `group` in your query criteria. I've updated my answer.